# Add new Link to Quick Launch Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, quick-launch

```
clientContext.Load(web);

NavigationNodeCollection oNavNodeCollection = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;

NavigationNodeCreationInformation oNewNaviNode = new NavigationNodeCreationInformation();
oNewNaviNode.Title = txtDisplayText.Text;
oNewNaviNode.Url = txtLinkAddress.Text;
oNewNaviNode.AsLastNode = true;


oNavNodeCollection.Add(oNewNaviNode);

clientContext.Load(oNavNodeCollection);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This code executed successfully but no result on Quick Launch Navigation!
SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code. It works perfectly for me.

```
var quickLaunchNodeCollection = null;
var oNewNaviNode = null;

function addNavigationNodes() {

    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    if (context != undefined && context != null) {

        var web = context.get_web();

        //this.navigationNodeCollection = web.get_navigation().get_topNavigationBar();
        this.quickLaunchNodeCollection = web.get_navigation().get_quickLaunch();

        // Set properties for a new navigation node.
        this.oNewNaviNode = new SP.NavigationNodeCreationInformation();
        oNewNaviNode.set_title("NewNavigationNode");
        oNewNaviNode.set_url("http://www.google.com");

        oNewNaviNode.set_asLastNode(true);
        this.quickLaunchNodeCollection.add(oNewNaviNode);

        context.load(this.quickLaunchNodeCollection);
        context.executeQueryAsync(addNavigationNodesSuccess, addNavigationNodesFailed);
    }
}

function addNavigationNodesSuccess() {
    alert("New node added...");
}

function addNavigationNodesFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but, I want C# code.